# AMC 258 engine after a rebuild is suddenly burning so much oil that it fouls plugs in 2 days

Tags: oil

1983 AMC 258 cubic inch newly rebuilt (1 year ago with low miles) suddenly has started burning so much oil that plugs are fouled in 2 days. What is the cause?

Comment: How many miles since the rebuild?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Comment: Are all the plugs fouled?

Comment: If it's burning that much oil, you should be seeing the smoke coming out of the tailpipe. Assuming this is correct, does the smoke come when accelerating or when decelerating (or both)?